# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float' when trying to pass interperpolate

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

Code:

```
cols = ["e_tbhiv_prct", "e_tbhiv_prct_lo", "e_tbhiv_prct_hi", "e_inc_tbhiv_100k", "e_inc_tbhiv_100k_lo",
       "e_inc_tbhiv_100k_hi", "e_inc_tbhiv_num", "e_inc_tbhiv_num_lo", "e_inc_tbhiv_num_hi"]

who[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)

who[cols].interpolate(method="nearest", axis=1)
```

I'm trying to interpolate missing data for the columns in `cols` (which are `float64`) however I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

which doesn't make sense given my columns are in the `float` format and are numeric. Do I need to transform these columns into  `int` first by executing something like:

```
who[cols] = who[cols].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method="nearest"), axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: your `cols` list seems to be a list of strings? How is it numeric?

Comment: I'm using cols to index my dataframe. Are you saying this is why it's breaking? Must they be a numeric index? Thanks @sai

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood. Not quite sure what the error is actually. Can you cross-check `who.dtypes` with the data types you expect them to have?

Comment: No worries. I can confirm the columns are in fact float64 meaning the interpolate() method should work

Comment: `apply` returns an updated dataframe. Try `df = who[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)` then `df.interpolate(...)`